# There is no ViewData item of type... issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm working on an intranet, precisely on an activity report system that lists the activity per week of an Employee. So I'm able to select the Employee in question with a `DropDownList` but I'm having issues with the selection.

```
   public ActionResult Client() // ReportIndex
    {
        [...]           
        string strEmployee = "-1";
        string strUser = User.Identity.Name;

        if (null != (string)Session["ReportEmployee"])
            strEmployee = (string)Session["ReportEmployee"];

        [...]

        ProjectResourceManagerService pr = new ProjectResourceManagerService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));
        //nea60
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> pl = pr.ListProject(strUser, strYear, strMonth);
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> pl2 = pr.ListEmployee();
        foreach (SelectListItem item in pl)
            if (item.Value == strProject)
                item.Selected = true;
        ViewBag.ProjectList = pl;
        foreach (SelectListItem item in pl2)
            if (item.Value == strEmployee)
                item.Selected = true;
        ViewBag.EmployeeList = pl2;

        //nea11
        Session["ReportYear"] = strYear;
        Session["ReportMonth"] = strMonth;
        //nea58
        Session["ReportProject"] = strProject;


        //nea58           

        return View();
    }
```

As you can see, `pl2` contains the list of Employees with the help of `pr.ListEmployee()`, the following `DropDownList` fills up :

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%:Html.DropDownList("Employee", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EmployeeList, "", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%></td>
```

But when I select an `Employee` it gives me the following error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Employee'.

I find it odd since the list *does* fill up with the names.

Comment: Because `ViewBag.EmployeeList` is `null` (most likely because you submit and in the POST method you return the view and have not repopulated ` `ViewBag.EmployeeList`)

Comment: Thank you ! Please post it as an answer so I can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the value of `ViewBag.EmployeeList` is `null` (in which case the fallback of `DropDownList()` is to use the first parameter as the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property).

Since you have correctly populated it in the GET method, the error is occuring because you return the view in the POST method and have not reassigned the value of `ViewBag.EmployeeList`