# How to save my dropdown list selected Item into my database?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I need to save a selected Item in my Database during User Registration. but it seems as if my selected Item is not recognised. here is the error that it's givin me

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'Faculties"

Am still unskilled in MVC/C# Programming please help here is my code below; thanks in advance!

My DataModel

```
public string Faculty { get; set; }
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
   DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
   ViewBag.Faculties = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");
   return View();
}
```

My View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Faculty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Faculties","Select Faculty")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Faculty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are placing the list of faculties in your `ViewBag`. Though you are calling for model.Faculty. Try using `ViewBag.Faculties` in your view or return the list of faculties to use it from the model `return View(faculties)`.

Comment: The error occurs because the value of `ViewBag.Faculties` is `null`, probably because in the POST method you return the view, but have not reassigned it as you did in the GET method. But since your model has property `Faculty ` then the view should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Faculty, (SelectList)ViewBag.Faculties, "Select Faculty")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type... issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098823/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-issue)

Comment: Thanx @StijnvanGaal for your reply sorry for only replying late. I have tried doing as you have suggested but the code gets errors. am getting my list from the Faculty Table in my Database. I just need my Item from the list to be added to the database when I have selected

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for your input I did as you said and we getting somewhere because now the only error it has is that The ViewData item that has the key 'Faculty' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'  if I understand the error correctly it's like the selected Item is a value but i'd like to convert it to string because i need to save that to my DBtable

Comment: Again, that is occurring because the value of `ViewBag.Faculties` is `null` (read my previous comment and the duplicate  linked to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are displaying items in the dropdown is not correct. You can use below code to display the items fetched from your db:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Faculties", ViewBag.Faculties as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
                       "Select Faculty");
```

Please note that your `ViewBag.Faculties` should be casted to `Enumerable<SelectListItem>`.

To get the selected value of dropdown in controller you can use below method:

```
var value = Request["Faculties"];
```

Once you got the value, you can save it in database.

**Update:**

A good approach will be to bind your View to a model which I think you have already done since I can see you are using `model.Faculty`. So the dropdown should look something like below in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList(model => model.Faculty,ViewBag.Faculties as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
                  "Select Faculty");
```

And your controller where data is posted should be something like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(YourModel model)
{
    var selectedFaculty = model.Faculty; //Selected Value
    //Save it in database
}
```

Comment: I did as you have suggested @Saket and I understand the logic for the view you gave me. and  for HttpPost I'm actually not too advanced in programming do you mind I understand the part where am supposed to get Faculties from DB var value = Request["Faculties"]; but I'm working on It to try implement it in my Controller. In My Controller am also adding other Fields for registration they can be saved perfectly to database the only problem i have is with this DropDown

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
ViewBag.Faculties = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");
```

to the following

```
ViewData["Faculties"] = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");
```

ViewBag and ViewData are two separate constructs, and cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: sorry for repplying late @Inari thanx I did as you said but still its giving me the same error. is this code in my view used correctly?  @Html.DropDownList("Faculties","Select Faculty")

Answer (score 1):

It's just the names of your property and your `ViewBag` are different. change your `ViewBag` name to match the property name.

```
ViewBag.Faculty = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");
```

Your HTML would be:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Faculty ","Select Faculty")
```

*Alternatively and (preferably) use a model binding instead of `ViewBag`*

**Model**

```
public string Faculty { get; set; }
public IList<SelectListItem> Faculties {get;set;}
```

**Controller**

```
Model.Faculties = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");
return View(Model);
```

**HTML (View)**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Faculty , Model.Faculties )
```

Comment: thanks soo much @Moe theres something I'm definately doing wrong here because its givin me more errors when i try to modify the code to match your suggestion. But thanks for the input. there are errors in Model.Faculties and return View(Moldel); in the controller